# Usando Login com Facebook em PHP

Tags: php, facebook

Estou tentando fazer login com facebook, usando o SDK 3.2.3.
Estou quase conseguindo, porém aparece a seguinte mensagem na tela:

```
"Warning The parameter app_id is required".
```

Segue o meu código:

```
   <?php
require_once ("facebook.php");

$config = array(
        'app_id' => 'yyyyyyyyyyyyy',
        'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'allowSignedRequest' =>  false,
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$uid = $facebook->getUser();

$params = array(
  'scope' => 'public_profile, user_friends, email',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.petsmatch.com.br'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

if($user_id) {

      try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }
```

Comment: voce mudou os caminhos? Definiu esse cara define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', '/path/to/fb-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/'); com o caminho dos arquivos do facebook e configurou o appid e pass? FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('YOUR_APP_ID', 'YOUR_APP_SECRET');

Comment: Não existe um "botão de login", é o seu botão/link html, ok? Dá uma olhada nesse tutorial: http://tableless.com.br/facebook-api-sdk-php-na-pratica-e-preview-de-como-aprovar-seu-aplicativo/

Comment: Alguém sabe o que significa essa mensagem?
"O URL informado não é permitido pela configuração do aplicativo: Uma ou mais dos URLs fornecidos não são permitidos nas configurações do aplicativo. O URL deve corresponder ao URL do site ou URL do Canvas, ou o domínio deve ser um subdomínio de um dos domínios do aplicativo."

Comment: Olá Gustavo, conseguiu resolver?